# "ATE1 E0" received over raw serial terminal over Bluetooth connection to a raspberry 3B+

Tags: bluetooth, raspberrypi

I am receiving "ATE1 E0" 3 times and after that twice some giberrish over the serial Bluetooth connection.

What could be the issue here? How do I fix it?

Comment: Do not add the solution to the question itself. Even if you want to share your findings (which is very much encouraged), you need to post as separate question and answer following the site's guidelines. You did the right thing by posting the answer below. Also do not add *[SOLVED]* to the question title. The right way to do it by "accepting" the most helpful answer. In case of your self-answer, you won't be able to do that right now, you need to wait a couple of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This relates to a AT Modem command and originates from the ModemManager service running on the Raspberry Pi. To fix it, just turn off the ModemManager service:

```
sudo systemctl stop ModemManager
```

Also you migth want to disable the ModemManager:

```
sudo systemctl disable ModemManager
```